# How do I limit or require the number of tags in a taxonomy reference field?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Similarly to how StackExchange requires tags on a question, how can I ensure the user uses at least four tags but no more than 8?

Comment: Is this for Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: For Drupal 7, the option for a max number of values is there by default in the field settings of your reference field (`admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENTTYPE/fields/FIELD`). Most of the time it's set to unlimited. If you set it to a number, the form validation will show an error if the user enters more than the specified number of values.

Comment: This is for Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module [field_validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) has an option for Number of selections which could be what you need without custom coding. For 7, there's a full release and for 8, there's an alpha.